# Swap the [swap]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request, retag-request

I just saw that there is a [swap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swap) tag on SO. Reading the excerpt:

> Changing position of two items.

Um... what? Let's read the wiki more closely:

> Act of rearranging the locations of two items such that the first item now occupies the place of the second and the second item now occupies the place of the first.

Uh... yeah, so, this is what swapping two items means, but... how would it be applied in the case of SO?

Apparently, [there are currently 1,808 questions with the [swap] tag](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswap%5Dis%3Aq). You only need to look at the top few results (in whatever ordering) to see that this tag has been used to mean different things, most of which are only tangentially related. For example, it's used both for the act of swapping two variables (`a, b = b, a`) and for swap memory (virtual RAM), two completely different topics.

Also, I don't really see the need for a [swap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swap) tag for swapping two entities, as it's a [meta tag](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/) in this case, since there are lots of different kinds of "swaps" one can do in a program (swapping two variables? swapping two characters? ...), each of which is a different beast, and the tag doesn't tell me even roughly what kind of swap the question is talking about, let alone that it obviously can't stand on its own.

As for the usage regarding virtual memory, we already have a [virtual-memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtual-memory) tag, which can be used for [these (currently 155) questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswap%5Dis%3Aq+memory) perfectly.

**Therefore, I'm suggesting a retagging of [swap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swap) questions to appropriate, non-meta and unambiguous tags wherever possible and worthy, and, subsequently, a burnination of the tag (removal of the tag from questions that aren't really worthy of a [swap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swap)-like tag at all).**

Let's check [the burnination criteria](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071/2474955):

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?** Definitely no to both, as described above.
2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?** Sure it is, in some cases, but obviously not always, if we take into account the vagueness of the tag wiki quoted above (e.g. "Should I swap the endpoints of these two cables?").
3. **Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?** At least for me, if somebody told me "I'm trying to swap stuff over here...", I'd just wonder what they're swapping in exactly the same way as I am after reading this tag's excerpt (see above).
4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?** One of the reasons that (1) is false is that this is false, as the tag has many different meanings.

Comment: Sorry to tell you, but I'm an *expert* in [swap]ping.

Comment: I would suggest adding a "swap-memory" tag as well and making it a synonym of "virtual memory" so that it pops up when people search for the tag with "swap"